# Any good yum repository management dashboards?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, configuration-management, rpm

I'm currently managing hundreds of CentOS/Amazon Linux servers, and our homegrown tools for managing the myriad package versions seems inadequate and unnecessary. What I'm looking for is a tool that each server would connect to and would then report what packages are installed and what their versions are. In essence, I would like to have a dashboard where I can easily see which servers are behind on their packages, and so need to run a yum update.

We are already using Chef for configuration management in general, but it doesn't quite solve this problem (at least not that I've seen).

I think Ubuntu has a service that does something like this, but I haven't seen anything for RedHat-flavored systems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/).

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Holy crap!  Bad mod, answering a shopping question.

Comment: "Spacewalk project has been discontinued on May 31 2020." Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Endpoint Manager for Patch Management provides RHEL patching dashboard and shows you exactly which systems need patched, and supports patch base-lining.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v26r1/topic/com.ibm.tem.doc_9.1/welcome/kc_welcome-patchmanagement91.html